# Which language would Knuth use to (re-)write TeX today?

Tags: tex-core, knuth, literate-programming, web

[ yes, this is "primarily opinion based;" VTC if you must ]

In [Literate Programming](http://www.literateprogramming.com/knuthweb.pdf) Knuth wrote:

> ... I chose PASCAL as the programming language ... ; it is not my favorite language for system programming, but it has become a
>   “second language” for so many programmers that it
>   provides an exceptionally effective medium of communication. ...

If DEK were writing (or re-writing) TeX today, what language would he choose? (It might be [CWEB](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/cweb.html), see his [FAQ](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/faq.html).)

It seems the C might have the same reach that PASCAL once did; although C++ is probably "better" than C in so many ways for a program like TeX (but C might be a "second language" for most C++ programmers).  ECMAScript is also widely available and well known, although it's not really intended for a program like TeX.  With C#/.NET now more-or-less cross-platform, maybe that's everybody's "second favorite language"? Of course, Java would be the "no Microsoft!" alternative to C#.

What language today might fulfill the same goals for TeX as PASCAL did in the early 80s?  This is (mostly) a TeX question because of some of its unique goals; without such "requirements," TeX might still be in [SAIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAIL_(programming_language)) or would be written in PL/1.

Comment: Perl, Java, C#, Haskell .... Fortran 54 ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer FORTRAN?  Be still my heart!

Comment: Yes, opinion-based. The only person who can answer this question is professor Knuth himself. And he might need a few minutes to think about it as well.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Ok, let's use assembly language....

Comment: @Dan Is that a question for a LaTeX community, or for a programming community?

Comment: Knuth was not interested in the language, he was interested in the *algorithms*. Any language would do... `:)`

Comment: Now answering your question: any Turing-complete language would do it. That's the requirement you are looking for.

Comment: Assembly language?  Oh @ChristianHupfer, you can do better than that.  Let's program my organization's original computer, using wire connectors: http://ftp.arl.army.mil/~mike/comphist/48eniac-coding/index.html.  It was a base-10 computer...binary computing hadn't been invented yet.  (in PDF form: http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/b205179.pdf)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I know you were one of the first ENIAC users :-P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I was a bit too young for that, but I worked with many people who did.  I learned FORTRAN from one of the original ENIAC programmers.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Your father?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, my Dad did not work at BRL.  His noteworthy contributions started at General Electric (as you likely noted in  my profile, http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes?tab=profile)

Comment: You mentioned "TeX had some particular/unique goals".  It might help narrow down the possible programming languages if you enumerated those goals.

Comment: I vote for JavaScript (not counting JSON). Apparently it can be hacked to do file operations.

Comment: Doesn't this question beg a prior question? Why think that Knuth *would* write TeX today?

Comment: @cfr DEK *really* is working on a reimplementation, please see [An earthshaking announcement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKaI78K_rgA&) :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Has, in fact, already announced one.